# CABasicAnimation inside UITableViewCell stops when reloading the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cabasicanimation

I create a `CABasicAnimation` in the `awakeFromNib` method of my `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
class TableviewCell: UITableViewCell { 

    @IBOutlet weak var viewToAnimate: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let hoverBasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        hoverBasicAnimation.isAdditive = true
        hoverBasicAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y:self.viewToAnimate.frame.origin.y))
        hoverBasicAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x:0, y: self.viewToAnimate.frame.origin.y +  30.0))
        hoverBasicAnimation.autoreverses = true
        hoverBasicAnimation.duration = 5
        hoverBasicAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        self.viewToAnimate.layer.add(hoverBasicAnimation, forKey: "hover animation")
    }
}
```

But when I reload the `UITableView` with making "pull to refresh" with the `UIRefreshControl`, the animation stops.

How can I prevent the animation stops when the `UITableView` is refreshed/reloaded?

Comment: Try to move that animation code to `animate()` method and call it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @alexburtnik I have did that and the animation it restart from the beginning. I want the animation keep moving

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @TàTruhoada I never found a solution